# Adjusting speed of flipping through a set of images with mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery, shuffle, mousemove

I am flipping through a set of images while moving the mouse. The images should flip in a random order. But the change itself is way too fast, it seems that it is now changing every pixel.

I tried to adjust the speed with a simple `if` condition, but it seems not to work.

My code looks like this:

```js
var slideshow = $(".introImages");
var images = $(".introImages img");
var pos = { x: 0, y: 0 };

$(slideshow).on("mousemove", function(event) {
  var x = event.pageX;
  var width = this.offsetWidth;

  var percentage = x / width;
  var random = Math.random(percentage);
  var imageNumber = Math.floor(random * images.length);

  if (
    event.pageX > pos.x + 100 ||
    event.pageY > pos.y + 100 ||
    event.pageY < pos.y - 100 ||
    event.pageX < pos.x - 100
  ) {
    $(images).each(function(image) {
      $(this).css("z-index", 0);
    });
    $(images)
      .eq(imageNumber)
      .css("z-index", 1);
  }
});
```

```css
*,
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.introImages {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}

.introImages img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.intrImages:first-child {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="introImages">
 <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563028327-1920b5a8d868?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556227703-ab57dbc6f839?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562960203-b4b41a48a1a1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559501418-12357e4cf8fd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1561015477-1c907845c96b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60">
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can see a live demo [here](https://codepen.io/Dennisade/pen/JQqKKx).

Answer (score 0):

You can set [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) in order to delay the change. Example with 1 second delay:

```js
        var slideshow = $(".introImages");
var images = $(".introImages img");
var pos = { x: 0, y: 0 };

$(slideshow).on("mousemove", function(event) {
  var x = event.pageX;
  var width = this.offsetWidth;

  var percentage = x / width;
  var random = Math.random(percentage);
  var imageNumber = Math.floor(random * images.length);

  if (
    event.pageX > pos.x + 100 ||
    event.pageY > pos.y + 100 ||
    event.pageY < pos.y - 100 ||
    event.pageX < pos.x - 100
  ) {
    $(images).each(function(image) {
      $(this).css("z-index", 0);
    });
    $(images)
      .eq(imageNumber)
      .css("z-index", 1);
  }
});
```

```css
*,html,body {
  margin: 0;
}

.introImages {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}

.introImages img {
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transition: z-index 1s;
  transition: z-index 1s;  
}

.intrImages:first-child {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="introImages">
 <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563028327-1920b5a8d868?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1556227703-ab57dbc6f839?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1562960203-b4b41a48a1a1?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559501418-12357e4cf8fd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1561015477-1c907845c96b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately its a bit buggy, and images are not live updating while the mouse is moving. Is there a fix I can do through js?